# Disabling and removing parity?

Tags: parity, installation, mac-osx

I have parity install on my Mac, even though I removed it via application folder. It's still running in the background. How can I remove it completely from my computer?

My localhost 8080 keeps routing to parity.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the uninstall script for Parity on Macs from https://github.com/ethcore/parity/blob/master/mac/uninstall-parity.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$SUDO_USER" == "" ]] ; then
    echo "This script requires elevated privileges."
    sudo $0
    exit;
fi

PLIST=~/Library/LaunchAgents/io.parity.ethereum.plist
su $SUDO_USER -c "launchctl stop io.parity.ethereum"
su $SUDO_USER -c "launchctl unload $PLIST"
rm -f /usr/local/libexec/parity /usr/local/libexec/uninstall-parity.sh /usr/local/bin/ethstore $PLIST
```

You can try searching for the uninstall script with the filename `uninstall-parity.sh`on your Mac and try running it, or just try executing the instructions manually.

---

### Update Feb 11 2017

To manually stop the Parity daemon:

```
sudo launchctl stop io.parity.ethereum
```

To remove the autostarting of the Parity daemon:

```
sudo launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/io.parity.ethereum.plist
```

To uninstall Parity, execute the script that is installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

The file mentioned in the [above solution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11360/17920) is now located here:

https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/master/mac/uninstall-parity.sh

Answer (score 0):

If you installed parity via homebrew then it should as easy as typing:

`brew uninstall parity`

This should both stop the services as well as uninstall the application completely.